# magento 2 multiple store views with sub domain url

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

I am trying to have two different store views with different themes but has the same catalog and settings.

default store view: **website.co.uk**
second store view should have: **migrate.website.co.uk**
[image]

Both the store views share the same website and store.
it is only the front end which changes.

I have created a sub domain of the main domain
I have copied **.htaccess** and **index.php** from **website.co.uk** to **migrate.website.co.uk** and modified **index.php** file as below:

```
<?php
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'migrate';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
?>
```

replacing

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

.

I have also added two lines at the start of htaccess file:

SetEnvIf Host **.*migrate.website.co.uk.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=migrate**
SetEnvIf Host **.*migrate.website.co.uk.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store**

when check the **migrate.website.co.uk** it shows me a blank page with 500 error.
what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend modifying the **index.php**.

This is a core file, meaning it'll simply get overwritten the next time you update Magento.

Since you're using **.htaccess** files I'm assuming you run apache.

In that case, you can use a virtual host configuration to share the website's files in the same directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          website.co.uk
    ServerAlias         "www.website.co.uk"
    DocumentRoot        /path/to/your/magento2/
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "default"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          migrate.website.co.uk
    DocumentRoot        /path/to/your/magento2/
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "migrate"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean I still need to copy both index.php and .htaccess into subdomain directory and configure the virtual host's file?

I am using plesk and have created the subdomain, my virtual hosts file looks like below:
I have two files under my sites-available:
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf

i will have to edit both default and ssl conf files.
port 7080 and 7081.

what if i am using website.co.uk/newweb/ as my second store by creating a new folder under magento root.
can i just place the environment variables on htaccess file on website.co.uk ?
like below:

SetEnvIf Host .*newstore.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=newweb

SetEnvIf Host .*newstore.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store